# Selenium test, Laravel on cPanel (centOS 7)

Tags: php, laravel, selenium-webdriver, centos, cpanel

we built a Laravel application that does automation test using selenium, we've installed chromedriver locally and ran several tests and all of them were successful.

but when we tried uploading it to a cPanel server running on CentOS7 it didn't work, we installed chromedriver package on cPanel but it also didn't work, is there a way we can make it work on cPanel?

this is what we're using in the controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnexpectedTagNameException;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverSelect;
```

and this is how the test is initiated inside the same contoller:

```
$capabilities = [
            'platform' => 'ANY',
            'browserName' => 'chrome',
        ];

        $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities);
```

the default port for chrome driver on localhost test was 4444, we were told that we cant connect ports to packages on cPanel, how do we solve this issue and run successful tests on the remote server?